# Can GeoServer Visualize 3D Vector and Raster Data?

Tags: 3d, gis, geoserver

I'm looking into using GeoServer for a project and need to visualize both vector (e.g., building outlines) and raster (e.g., elevation models) data in 3D. I've found plenty of information on 2D capabilities but am unclear about 3D support.

1. Does GeoServer directly support 3D visualization for vector and
   raster data?
2. What extensions or tools are recommended for 3D
   visualization in GeoServer?
3. Can GeoServer work with external 3D
   libraries (like CesiumJS) for visualization?
4. Are there examples or tutorials specifically about 3D data visualization with GeoServer?

Any advice or pointers towards resources would be greatly appreciated.